# Agile Classes.jar file

Tags: eclipse, agile, oracle-agile-plm

I am using Agile PLM Version: 9.3.0.2 (Build 20). I am on the client side. I'm trying to use Eclipse to interact with Agile's API features. According to the Agile SDK Developer Guide I need both:

AgileAPI.jar
agileclasses.jar

I have the AgileAPI.jar file, but I don't have the agileclasses.jar file.

Any suggestions/links/ methods in which I can obtain this file!

Answer (score 0):

AgileAPI.jar, contains the factories and interfaces used by the Agile EJB on server side.
If you have an Agile instance on a server, you don't need to have agileclasses.jar (unofficial API) but creating an IAgileSession using AgileSessionFactory, all the implementation of interfaces (IChange, IPrograms, IItem. etc) are retrieved using it.

```
session.getObject(IChange.OBJECT_TYPE, "ChangeNumber123");
```

where did you find that agileclasses.jar is required? 
However, you can find them in the Weblogic Server shared lib folder.

EDIT

Eclipse interacts with an Agile Server using AgileAPI.jar.

```
String server = "http://myServer:7001/Agile";

HashMap<Integer,String> params = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
AgileSessionFactory instance = AgileSessionFactory.getInstance(server);              

params.put(AgileSessionFactory.USERNAME, "myUsername");
params.put(AgileSessionFactory.PASSWORD, "myPassword");
IAgileSession session=instance.createSession(params);
IItem item = (IItem) session.getObject(IItem.OBJECT_TYPE, "ITEMID1234");
item.setValue("Page Two.MYFIELD", "Value");
```

The example above, connect to an instance of Agile (server) already started up and get the item  with number `ITEMID1234`. Then it sets the value of a field (MYFIELD) with "Value"

Comment: SDK Developer Document

Comment: Do you mean the following
Configuring the SDK Network Classloader and Weblogic Server Operability?
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10959_06/otn/pdf/integration/B32316_01.pdf

THis is not to configue your eclipse but the server. At the end, it says that these files are available under $AGILE_HOME/agileDomain/lib but it is not to use your eclipse as application container to run it

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. Ideally I would like to use eclipse to somehow interact with Agile. But I'm not sure how to configure it. I wish I could use Python but it looks like only Java works with it.

Comment: Yes it works only with java and groovie (only using the java client). However this chapter is not for what you want because you need a server configured in that way and with an Agile instance installed. Once you have that, you can interact with it using only AgileAPI.jar

Comment: So can I use Eclipse to interact with Agile? Or does Eclipse interact with AgileAPI.jar using Java? Is there documentation for this? I'm looking for examples so I can start somewhere.

Comment: I am updating my answer

Comment: I'm curious as to why Python isn't a recommended or valid choice of language to interact with Agile. I've written similar scripts that would require me to ping a server, enter my credentials then store a value of the given data I am trying to retrieve.